# How can I send values of multiple select option fields to a controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails, hash, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a form for a model "Cell" that can be cloned using `javascript`. I have both text fields and select fields in the form that can be cloned. Since the cloned element produces an array of Strings, I have sent the text elements as an array by changing the name attribute of the field using the format: `cell[ ]['name']`. However, `f.select` field in rails comes with a default name attribute `cell[category_id]`. Due to this, I keep getting the error:

```
Invalid request parameters: expected Hash (got Array) for param `cell'.
```

This is the code:

```rb
= form_for @cell do |f|
  #clone
    .form.rowField
      = f.text_field :name, name: 'cell[][name]', class: "form-control"
      = f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.pluck('name'))
      i.fas.fa-plus-circle#addrow
    = f.submit "Save", class: "button btn btn-primary"
```

The javascript code for cloning the form is

```js
$('#addrow').click(function () {
        var row = document.querySelector('.rowField');
        var cloneRow = row.cloneNode(true);
        var target = document.querySelector('#clone');
        cloneRow.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function (input) {
            input.value = "";
        });
        target.appendChild(cloneRow);
    });
```

Is there a way to change to name attribute of the select tag from `cell[category_id]` to `cell[][category_id]`?

Comment: Rails' form helper select has an option for `multiple: true`. That may help. Also what do your strong params look like?

Comment: @Shristina is both category and name fields are array in the model? Also, if these are array can you please try `'cell[name][]'` in name text field and `'cell[category_id][]'` in the select as name and try. For select update the name like below. 
`= f.select 'cell[category_id][]'`
If this works for you let me I will post in answer.

Comment: What is the user story here? And not just clone the entire form instead? This looks like a really awkward attempt at a multi-create action.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the name of the select field as:

```rb
= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.pluck('name')), {}, {name: 'cell[][category_id]'}
```